# How to bind and unbind a third party jQuery library function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I've created code to add a table row with a form field, and try to bind the 3rd party SuggestBox function to each dynamically generated form field.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form1').validationEngine();
    var newRowNum = 1;
    $(".addRow").click(function(){
        var $newTr = $("#tb1 tbody>tr:last").clone(true);
        $newTr.find('input[id^=foods]').unbind(jsonSuggest());  <== try to unbind the previouse jsonsuggest()
        //$newTr.find('.jsonSuggestResults').remove();
        $newTr.appendTo("#tb1 tbody");
        $('input[id^=foods]', $newTr).val('');
        $newTr.find('input[id^=foods]').each(function(){
            $(this).jsonSuggest(
                    function(text, wildCard, caseSensitive, notCharacter) {
                        rez = $.ajax({ 
                            type: 'GET', 
                            url: 'getFoodJSON.jsp',
                            data: 'foods=' + text,
                            dataType: 'json', 
                            async: false 
                        });
                        return eval(rez.responseText); 
                        },
                        { ajaxResults:true 
                        });
        });
        $newTr.find('input[id^=supplyDate]').each('id', function(){
            $(this).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
        });
    });
});
```

However, the SuggestBox suggestions accumulate duplicates. Here is the result when I input something at row 7...

[link text](http://www.javaworld.com.tw/jute/gallery/d/2/d2ViZGluZ3M=/1257902462423.png)

Would you mind to telling me how to unbind the applied function at the previous row+form field? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By writing `unbind(jsonSuggest())`, you are *calling* `jsonSuggest` and unbinding the value that it returns.  Unless the `jsonSuggest` function is a generator that returns a handler method (which it probably isn't), that's not what you want.  If it is, that's still not what you want, unless it returns the same handler every time.

You want (I assume) to unbind the `jsonSuggest` function itself by writing `unbind(jsonSuggest)`, without parentheses.